# Onclick Reload page

Tags: php

Hi currently i have a problem with my Onclick because it wont reload on my page
This is what i have.

```
       <div id="vpanel">
        <div>
        <form method="post" action="enrollalpha.php">
        <label>View Panel</label>
        <select name="Vpanel" onclick="return.this.form">
                              <option value="VS">Students</option>
                              <option value="VSc">Section</option>
                              <option value="VA">Adviser</option></select>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
```

And will be used in this code on the same page.

```
        <form method="post" action="">

        <div id="tbody"  class="scrollbar">
    <?php
         if(!empty($_POST['Vpanel'])){
         $vview = $_POST['Vpanel'];
         }else{
           $vview = 'VS';
        }
        if($vview == 'VS'){
            require_once 'vpanel_student.php';
        }else if($vview == 'VSc'){
            require_once 'vpanel_section.php';
        }else if($vview == 'VA'){
            require_once 'vpanel_adviser.php';
        }else{
            require_once 'vpanel_student.php';
        }
    ?>

        </div>
```

Would appreciate any help on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: do you want to refresh page on change of select box option?

Comment: @SLAYER Yes currently its not reloading I'm not sure whats wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `this.form.submit()` and `onchange()`:

```
<select name="Vpanel" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="VS">Students</option>
    <option value="VSc">Section</option>
    <option value="VA">Adviser</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

replace you code with below line

```
<select name="Vpanel" onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace onclick by onchange because you want to submit your form when your option selected change and not when you click on your select and use this.form.submit();

Or use this html :

```
<form id="form-vpanel" method="post" action="enrollalpha.php">
    <label>View Panel</label>
    <select id="vpanel" name="Vpanel">
        <option value="VS">Students</option>
        <option value="VSc">Section</option>
        <option value="VA">Adviser</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

With this JQuery :

```
$('#vpanel').change(function() {
    $('#form-vpanel').submit();
});
```